# Replace NaN with zeros in cell array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, replace, nan, cell-array

I have a 50x25 cell array in the variable `raw_data`. Each cell contains a 200x150 matrix. I have a few `NaN` values scattered between all those values and I want to set them to `zeros` to make sure they do not interfere at later stages.

I have tried the following:

```
raw_data(cellfun(@(x) any(isnan(x), raw_data, 'UniformOutput', false)) = 0
```

When running the script, I get "Function 'subindex' is not defined for values of class 'cell'". Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably the best way is to use a `for` loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
cellfun(@(x) nansum(x,ndims(x)+1), raw_data, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Note if you're certain you'll only have 2D matrices in `raw_data` you can replace the `ndims(x)+1` with `3`.

The idea is to use `nansum` to sum along the 3rd dimension as this will preserve the shape of the first 2 dimensions and luckily `nansum` seems to convert `NaN` to `0` when all the elements being summed are `NaN`

Comment: Also you can shorten `'UniformOutput', false` to `'uni',0` if you like. In fact I think you can even do `'u',0`